Excel VBA - PasteSpecial Method - The code does what it should but I still receive an error: thus it does not fully run
I have this Excel VBA code that runs perfectly and does exactly what it should, up until this line:
csvSheet.Range("B5").Resize(colBValues.Rows.Count, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

This code needs to the data from tables of other sheets, put it into the ManualJournal Sheet and then save that ManualJournal sheet as a seperate .csv file. It does that, but when the date column is copied over, the format of the dates changes, which means that 1 September changes to 9 January. The problem with that is this csv file needs to be imported to Xero but the wrong dates will lead to wrong data.
The problem now is, with the PasteSpecial method, it copies the date over well and all of the data is perfect, but it still gives me an error and does not perform the instructions that comes after this line. Error message received

A Runtime 1004 error is generated saying the PasteSpecial Method of Range Class failed

Sub CSVDateFormat()
    ' Define variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim destWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim tableData As Range
    Dim startString As String
    Dim destSheetName As String
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim amountCol As Range
    Dim sumAmount As Double
    Dim amountColNumber As Long
    Dim amountHeader As String
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim baseFileName As String
    Dim dateInA1 As String  ' New variable for the date in A1
    Dim csvFilePath As String
    Dim csvWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim colBValues As Range ' New variable for column B values
    Dim csvSheet As Worksheet ' New variable for the CSV sheet

    ' Set the string that worksheet names should start with
    startString = "Amort"  ' Prefix for the worksheets to copy from
    
    ' Set the destination worksheet name
    destSheetName = "ManualJournal"  ' Destination worksheet
    
    ' Set the amount column header name (change to match your column header)
    amountHeader = "*Amount"  ' Change this if the "Amount" column has a different name
    
    ' Set the destination worksheet in the same workbook
    Set destWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(destSheetName)
    
    ' Initialize the last row to start pasting data (start from row 5)
    lastRow = 5
    
    ' Loop through each worksheet in the active workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Check if the sheet name starts with the specified string
        If Left(ws.Name, Len(startString)) = startString Then
            ' Check if the worksheet contains any tables
            If ws.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
                ' Loop through all tables on the worksheet
                For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
                    ' Get the table data excluding headers
                    Set tableData = tbl.DataBodyRange
                    
                    ' Only proceed if the table has data
                    If Not tableData Is Nothing Then
                        ' Get the number of rows in the table to be copied
                        rowCount = tableData.Rows.Count
                        
                        ' Find the next available row on the destination sheet (after last used row)
                        If lastRow = 5 Then
                            ' If it's the first entry, paste starting at row 5
                            tableData.Copy
                            destWorksheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                            ' Update lastRow to reflect the newly pasted data
                            lastRow = lastRow + rowCount
                        Else
                            ' Otherwise, paste after the last row
                            lastRow = destWorksheet.Cells(destWorksheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            tableData.Copy
                            destWorksheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                            ' Update lastRow to reflect the newly pasted data
                            lastRow = lastRow + rowCount
                        End If
                    End If
                Next tbl
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    
    ' Find the "Amount" column in the destination sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    amountColNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(amountHeader, destWorksheet.Rows(4), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Check if the "Amount" column was found
    If amountColNumber > 0 Then
        ' Sum the "Amount" column starting from row 5 to the last row with data
        Set amountCol = destWorksheet.Range(destWorksheet.Cells(5, amountColNumber), _
                                            destWorksheet.Cells(lastRow - 1, amountColNumber))
        sumAmount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(amountCol)
        
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: 'Amount' column not found in the ManualJournal sheet.", vbCritical
    End If
    
    ' Convert Column B in the ManualJournal sheet to text format
    Set rng = destWorksheet.Range("B5:B" & lastRow - 1)
    For Each cell In rng
        ' If the cell contains a date, format it as "yyyy/MM/dd" and force it to be text
        If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
            cell.Value = "'" & Format(cell.Value, "yyyy/MM/dd")
        Else
            ' Convert any other value to text
            cell.Value = "'" & cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Get the date from cell A1 in "ManualJournal" and format it
    dateInA1 = Format(destWorksheet.Range("A1").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") ' Ensures the date is formatted correctly for filenames
    
    ' Set the active worksheet (the one where the button is placed)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ' Define the save path
    savePath = ThisWorkbook.Path ' This saves in the same directory as the current workbook

    ' Get the base file name of the current workbook without the extension
    baseFileName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)

    ' Define the file name using the workbook's base name and the date from A1
    fileName = baseFileName & " - Manual Journal - " & dateInA1 & ".csv"

    ' Save the active sheet as a csv file (.csv)
    ws.Copy ' Creates a new workbook with only the active sheet
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=savePath & "\" & fileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV

    ' Close the newly saved workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    
    ' Pause briefly to ensure the file is saved completely
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) ' Pause for 2 seconds
    
    ' Define the full path to the saved CSV file
    csvFilePath = savePath & "\" & fileName

    ' Open the saved CSV file
    Set csvWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(csvFilePath)
    Set csvSheet = csvWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' Reference the CSV sheet

    ' Copy column B from the ManualJournal sheet
    Set colBValues = destWorksheet.Range("B5:B" & lastRow - 1)
    
    ' Check if there are any values to copy
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(colBValues) > 0 Then
         'Paste column B values into column B of the CSV sheet starting from cell B5 (to preserve headers)
        csvSheet.Range("B5").Resize(colBValues.Rows.Count, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If


    ' Delete the first 3 rows (adjust this as needed)
    csvSheet.Rows("1:3").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
    ' Ensure data is in Column A
    csvSheet.Columns("A:A").Select
    
    ' Convert text to columns using commas as the delimiter
    csvSheet.Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False
    
    ' Save and close the workbook
    csvWorkbook.Save
    csvWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub



I tried to use ChatGPT to solve this problem but after changing the code with what the AI advised and also what I thought may be wrong, other the date clumn still does not show the data it should or the code does not run at all. I am unsure where to go from here.

It's hard to follow all your code, you should limit the code you show to the relevant part. That said: I assume there is nothing to paste at the moment the error occurs. At least I don't see any .Copy command. Anyhow, as you want to copy only values, it's usually better (faster) not to use C&P but to write the values directly into the cells.

It sounds like you have US date convention and ROW date convention mixed up in some strange way during the data transfer. With copy and paste crystalising the wrong date structure.  Dates outside the range 1/1 to 12/12 inclusive will be invalid in one of the two formats. BTW Your code looks nothing like a minimum reproducible example. It would also help to know country code and other localisation details. We need to see a sample of the imported CSV file with a few dates that are unambiguous too.

Just to focus on @FunThomas's reply: there is no preceded Copy command.

I have, after playing around with the code again, added the copy command explicitly and also added the command to clear the clipboard after the data is pasted into the csv file. That did solve the problem. So thank you for the answers and help. I am new to VBA and still trying to learn.

I have, after playing around with the code again, added the copy command explicitly and also added the command to clear the clipboard after the data is pasted into the csv file. That did solve the problem. The data text is pasted over correctly and not in the date format, as the .csv file changes the dates itself. Now that it is pasted over as text, it works 100%.
